# How to include 2 checks in a if statement

Tags: php

Basically I am coding a script where it simply redirects the user to the destination page. And I want to be able to check if multiple websites are not equal to the value; if this is so, it will run a error, else it will proceed.

I can't seem to get this to work though, although I am sure there's a way to check multiple values.

```
 <?php
$url = $_GET['site']; // gets the site URL the user is being redirected to.

if ($url != "***.co", "***.net")
    {
    echo ("Website is not valid for redirection.");
    } else {
    echo ("You are being redirected to: " . $url);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make an array of items to check for and then check if the url is in the array:

```
if (!in_array($url, array("***.co", "***.net")))
{
}
```

You can also use multiple conditions like @wrigby showed, but the solution using an array makes it easier to add more (or a dynamic number of) urls. But if there are always two, his is better.

Comment: Cheers :) Although there's a missing ) at the end of the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two complete conditionals, connected with a logical and (&&) operator:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['site']; // gets the site URL the user is being redirected to.

if ($url != "***.co" && $url != "***.net")
    {
    echo ("Website is not valid for redirection.");
    } else {
    echo ("You are being redirected to: " . $url);
    }
?>
```

Comment: @user3601641 You may also want to consider calling strtolower on the URL, so that if upper case URLs are passed in, your conditional still works correctly: `$url = strtolower($_GET['site'])`